# removing appended elements with onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am having three input fields and a button when I click the button the values should be append to the next input fields that works prefect .But the problem is that I have a remove button along with the appended elements when I click the button the specific values has to be removed but it removes every thing, this is my code,

JS :

```
var ins_add_Gst_Name    =   $("#ins-add-guest-name").val();
var ins_add_Gst_Age     =   $("#ins-guest-age").val();
var ins_add_Gst_rel     =   $("#ins-guest-relation").val();
if (ins_add_Gst_Name != '') {

                    list_name           =   $("#ins-add-guest-name-disp").append('<input class="form-control input-md" value="'+ins_add_Gst_Name+'" id="ins-add-guest-name-disp">').append('<br />').append('<br />');
                    list_reln           =   $("#ins-guest-relation-disp").append('<input class="form-control input-md" value="'+ins_add_Gst_rel+'" id="ins-guest-relation-disp">').append('<br />').append('<br />');
                    list_age            =   $("#ins-guest-age-disp").append('<input class="form-control input-md" value="'+ins_add_Gst_Age+'" id="ins-guest-age-disp">').append('<br />').append('<br />'); 
                    list_btns           =   $("#ins-guest-btn-disp").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" >').append('<br />').append('<br />'); 

}
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function() {
                    var sample_name = $(this).parents("form").children("#ins-guest-name").children("#ins-add-guest-name-disp").html("");
var sample_reln = $(this).parents("form").children("#ins-guest-relation").children("#ins-guest-relation-disp").html("");
                    var sample_age  = $(this).parents("form").children("#ins-guest-age").children("#ins-guest-age-disp").html("");
});
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">Guest Name</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-md" id="ins-add-guest-name" name="ins-add-guest-name" placeholder="Guest Name" value="" required autofocus></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">Relation</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-md" id="ins-guest-relation" name="ins-guest-relation" placeholder="Relation Ship" value="" required autofocus></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">Age</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" ><input class="form-control input-md" id="ins-guest-age" name="ins-guest-age" placeholder="Age" value="" required autofocus></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name='ins-add-save-guest' id='ins-add-save-guest' value="Save Updates">Save Details</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

HERE what I am displaying the appended elements :

```
  <div class="row" id="Welcome" >

        <form class="form-inline" >
        <div class="form-group" id="ins-guest-name">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="ins-add-guest-name-disp"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="ins-guest-relation">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="ins-guest-relation-disp" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="ins-guest-age">
        <div class="col-md-4"  id="ins-guest-age-disp" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4"  id="ins-guest-btn-disp" ></div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

and I need a solution like when I click the button I need to remove the element with the particular button clicked

ie,

```
<input value="R" id="s"> <input value="B"><input value="23"> <button>
<input value="H" id="K"> <input value="M"><input value="55"> <button>
```

when I click the first button it should remove all elements belongs to the particular button.

so the result should be ,

```
<input value="H" id="K"> <input value="M"><input value="55"> <button>
```

I am pretty new to jquery any help will be really appreciated

EDIT :

This is the link
           (jsfiddle.net/jy664t5L)

Comment: `....when I click the 'span' .....`  which `span` are you talking about?

Comment: @ Sandeep Nayak <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">

Comment: please format your code

Comment: @ SpringLearner   can you please explain me how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Hey Vishnu Your code lit bit confusing, as  per your last 2 lines

```
"<input value="R" id="s"> <input value="B"><input value="23"> <button>
<input value="H" id="K"> <input value="M"><input value="55"> <button>"
```

you can do like this

```
<div><input value="R" id="s"> <input value="B"><input value="23"> <button>  </div>
<div><input value="H" id="K"> <input value="M"><input value="55"> <button></div>

$("button").click(function() {$(this).parent().remove()});
```

Comment: It does not working forgive me for the confusion . The thing is that I need to remove the appended elements by clicking the corresponding button

Comment: can you share me the element structure which has to be removed? and the button in which you want to perform an action

Comment: or copy your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ like http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgdte09/
 so that would be easier to understand

Comment: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">, It does the operation when we clicks . It actually append to <div class="col-md-4"  id="ins-guest-btn-disp" ></div> ,

Comment: Thanks for your comment , here is the link        http://jsfiddle.net/jy664t5L/   . Its not working as I need when adding more than one datas

Comment: @ Jainandan singh baghel thanks bro , but that is not I wanted . When I  click the first  "remove " sign first row should be removed not all the row like wise the second too.

Comment: the update code link is doing the same 
"when you click the remove button , it remove one row, again you click on it , it remove another one row.